# Update viewCount on every hit in redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I'm using Redis to cache an object. I want to maintain a count of hits on redis for a particular key. For example,
This is the key value pair I'm storing key value as below in Redis.
`<customerId, customerDetails>`

```
public class CustomerDetails {
  public String name;
  public String phoneNumber;
  public int viewCount;
}
```

I want to update viewCount whenever redis cache is hit. I'm not sure how can I use opsforValue to increment a value in an object.

I've tried out something like this:

```
    String viewCount = valueOps.get(String.valueOf(customerId));
    System.out.println("viewCount " + viewCount );
    if(viewCount == null) {
        System.out.println("adding new key value");
        valueOps.set(String.valueOf(customerId), maxRate, 25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        allow = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("increasing value");
        valueOps.increment(String.valueOf(customerId), 1);
        if(Integer.parseInt(viewCount ) > 0) {
            allow = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to implement rate limiting, is that correct?

Comment: yes, but I can't use bucket4J or any other library. I'm unable to update a single variable in cache. Tried using cacheput but in vain